# CSS Transitions code

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on IOS app like web widget in html, for which i need transition (slide from right) effect (in CSS) while navigating from a page to other and when reloaded. Can you suggest (code) with CSS for applying Transition.

Comment: I don't think CSS transitions are appropriate here.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Me neither, but I just answered the question anyway...

Comment: stackoverflow isn't  code writing service .. first get some book .learn them and try and that time if you have any problem we would love to help you ...

Comment: @NullPointer Thanks for the edit, and supporting my point :)

Comment: @MarkRobinson yours very welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

So read this: http://www.usabilitypost.com/2011/04/19/pure-css-slideout-interface/

```
<div id="slideout">
  <img src="feedback.png" alt="Feedback" />
  <div id="slideout_inner">
    [form code goes here]
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/css3-transitions-and-transforms-from-scratch/

This is a pretty good tutorial on how you can go about doing css3 transitions. Additionally it is helpful if you post what you've already tried so that way people can have an idea of what you specifically want.